# Twilio Video Recording using external s3

Tags: javascript, twilio, video-recording, twilio-video

Can someone explain how to start and stop video recording programmatically to an external s3 bucket using twilio video and javascript? In the twilio console I can see a start recording on join option. I do not need this. I want to be able to control when to start and stop the recording. Is this possible? I couldnt find any resource in the docs related to this specific topic. (Maybe I missed it?)

If someone has implemented something similar please help me out with some implementation tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Twilio provides an [api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recording-rules)  which can be used to achieve my requirement. I can get the desired effect by toggling the rule type from "include" to "exclude"